# How to compute gradient wrt concatenated variables in theano

Tags: gradient, theano

I have a loss function `y` which is a function of multiple **shared variables** `theta1`, `theta2`, ...

Then, gradient descent of `y` wrt `theta` s can be written simply as

```
import theano.tensor as T
theta_list = [theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4]
grad_list = T.grad(y, theta_list)
for theta, gradient in zip(theta_list, grad_list):
    theta = theta - learning_rate * gradient
```

However I want not to use the list representation of `theta`. That is,

```
import theano.tensor as T
thetas = <Properly concatenate thetas>
gradient = T.grad(y, thetas)
thetas = thetas - learning_rate * gradient
```

Is there any way to enable this?

Simple **thetas = T.concatenate(theta_list)** raises **DisconnectedInputError** when calculate the gradient.

Comment: Can you share a bit more code on how the `theta_list` and `y` is constructed? Maybe add a minimal working example that showcases the problem

Comment: @MakisTsantekidis `y` is a resulting tensor of Convolutional Neural Network, and `theta_list` is a list of kernels and weight matrices.